# Condensing Multiple List Comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list with input in this form:

```
open_info = ['Cube 1, 9:30am to 10:00am, Thursday, March 3, 2016', 'Cube 2, 5:00pm to 5:30pm, Thursday, March 3, 2016']
```

I want to parse through this information to create a new list in this form:

```
open_times = [[9, 30, 'am'],[5, 0, 'pm']]
```

With the hour at first index, minutes at second, and am/pm at the third index. I am only recording the first time value for each list element, because the intervals I am dealing with are always 30 minutes long.

I have accomplished this by using the following python list comprehensions:

```
open_times = [x.split(",")[1].replace(" ","").split("to") for x in open_info]
open_times = [x[0].split(":")+x[1].split(":") for x in open_times]
open_times = [[int(x[0]),int(x[1][:2]),x[1][2:]] for x in open_times]
```

I was wondering if there was to create a nested list comprehension out of all of these. I've looked at the python documentation and read some blogs on the subject but I'm still having trouble accomplishing this.

Comment: Would you be opposed to a non-list comprehension solution?  Y'know, so that one could properly digest the actual problem?  As a further question, what length of list are you expecting to have?

Comment: Echoing the above comment, can you explain why you want/need to do this using list comprehensions rather than a more traditional (and readable) parsing function?

Comment: I would not all be opposed to that. I'm relatively new to python so I'm trying to learn more about things I have difficulty with by practicing them. I'm aware that this solution is messy so that's why I came here. And to answer your other question, the list length is variable but it will always be somewhere between 0 and a few hundred. @Makoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
open_info = ['Cube 1, 9:30am to 10:00am, Thursday, March 3, 2016', 'Cube 2, 5:00pm to 5:30pm, Thursday, March 3, 2016']

answer = [[int(s.split(':',1)[0][-2:]), int(s.split(':')[1][:2]), 
           s.split(':')[1][2:4]] for s in open_info]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[9, 30, 'am'], [5, 0, 'pm']]
```

In these circumstances, however, it may be more readable to use `map` instead of a `list` comprehension:

```
def func(s):
    hour = int(s.split(':')[0][-2:])
    minute = int(s.split(':')[1][:2])
    suffix = s.split(':')[1][2:4]
    return [hour, minute, suffix]

answer = map(func, open_info)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[9, 30, 'am'], [5, 0, 'pm']]
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question of how to 'nest' list comprehensions, you might do this to combine lines 1 and 2....

```
open_times = [y[0].split(":")+y[1].split(":") for y in [x.split(",")[1].replace(" ","").split("to") for x in open_info]]
```

... but this is really messy.  The 3 lines are more understandable and cleaner here.  You might also think about writing this as a series of loops since there's a lot going on inside the comprehension that would be cleaner outside of one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for extracting the times:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> [[int(val) if val.isdigit() else val for val in re.search(r'(\d+):(\d+)(am|pm)',item, re.I).groups()] for item in open_info]
[[9, 30, 'am'], [5, 00, 'pm']]
```

But not that it might raise an `AttributeError` if it can't match the regex so if you are not sure about that you can us a `try-except` expression to handle the error.

```
times = []
for item in open_info:
    match = re.search(r'(\d+):(\d+)(am|pm)',item, re.I)
    try:
        h, m, b = match.groups()
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        pass # or append a proper value to times, instead.
    else:
        times.append([int(h), int(m), b])
   times.append(match)
```

Comment: Nice, deleting comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pushing all the logic to list comprehension expresion you may simply create processing function.

I renamed some values for better readability.

```
def extract(s):
    time_from, time_to = s.split(",")[1].replace(" ", "").split("to")
    hour, min_am_pm = time_from.split(":")
    min = min_am_pm[:2]
    am_pm = min_am_pm[2:]
    return [int(hour), int(min), am_pm]


open_info = ['Cube 1, 9:30am to 10:00am, Thursday, March 3, 2016', 'Cube 2, 5:00pm to 5:30pm, Thursday, March 3, 2016']
open_times = [extract(x) for x in open_info]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from csv import reader
answer = [[int(a), int(b[:2]), c[2:]] for a, b, c in (inf[1].split(":")
             for inf in reader(open_info, skipinitialspace=True))]
```

Which actually matches your expected output:

```
[[9, 30, 'am'], [5, 0, 'pm']]
```

A simple function would be a better idea, also don't need to continually keep splitting the same line repeatedly:

```
def spl(l):
    for inf in l:
        a, b, c = inf.split(", ", 2)[1].split(":", 2)
        yield [int(a), int(b[:2]), c[2:]]

print(list(spl(open_info)))
```

Output:

```
[[9, 30, 'am'], [5, 0, 'pm']]
```

Or letting the csv lib parse the items:

```
from csv import reader

def spl(l):
    for inf in reader(l, skipinitialspace=True):
        a, b, c = inf[1].split(":", 2)
        yield [int(a), int(b[:2]), c[2:]]
print(list(spl(open_info)))
```